# What is this `@sp` syntax in this quick sort code for scala?

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand this quick sort code from the following [repo](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/core/shared/src/main/scala/spire/math/Sorting.scala)

```
  object QuickSort {
    @inline final def limit: Int = 16

    final def sort[@sp A:Order:ClassTag](data:Array[A]): Unit = qsort(data, 0, data.length - 1)

    final def qsort[@sp A](data:Array[A], left: Int, right: Int)(implicit o:Order[A], ct:ClassTag[A]): Unit = {

      if (right - left < limit) return InsertionSort.sort(data, left, right + 1)

      val pivot = left + (right - left) / 2
      val next = partition(data, left, right, pivot)
      qsort(data, left, next - 1)
      qsort(data, next + 1, right)
    }

    final def partition[@sp A](data:Array[A], left:Int, right:Int, pivot:Int)(implicit o:Order[A], ct:ClassTag[A]): Int = {

      val value = data(pivot)

      //swap(pivot, right)
      var tmp = data(pivot); data(pivot) = data(right); data(right) = tmp

      var store = left
      var i = left
      while (i < right) {
        if (o.lt(data(i), value)) {
          //swap(i, store)
          tmp = data(i); data(i) = data(store); data(store) = tmp
          store += 1
        }
        i += 1
      }
      //swap(store, right)
      tmp = data(store); data(store) = data(right); data(right) = tmp
      store
    }
  }
```

What is the purpose of `[@sp A]` ? I know `[A]` syntax is for generics, but what does adding `@sp` do? Can someone shed some insight on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

`@sp` is an alias for `@specialized` that is defined in the [spire package object](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/core/shared/src/main/scala/spire/package.scala).

We are using specialization ***a lot*** in spire, so having to write `@specialized` or renaming in imports got too tedious.

Note that the definitions from the spire package object will only be visible form subpackages if you have individual package statements.

So this works

```
package spire
package math

class Foo[@sp T]
```

Whereas this would not

```
package spire.math

class Foo[@sp T]
```

The same approach is used in the scala standard library. If you look at a class like [scala.collection.immutable.Set](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.0-M4/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Set.scala#L1), note that the package statement is done in three parts

```
package scala
package collection
package immutable
```